# How to get the executable file name from a window handle?

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have this code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  MyHandle: THandle;
begin
  MyHandle:=FindWindow(nil, 'Delphi');
  SendMessage(MyHandle, WM_CLOSE, 0, 0);
 // Here will be a message like ' title found and it's test.exe that has 'Delphi' Title
end;
```

For example, it is `test.exe` that is the process that has the `'Delphi'` title, and I want to get the EXE file name of that process by using the window handle. Is that possible? If so, may I have some reference for doing it?

Comment: [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) + [`OpenProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) + [`GetProcessImageFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sv-se/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamea?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a procedure which I use, which you are likely to find in other places on the internet. I don't recall the exact source, it may have been https://www.swissdelphicenter.ch.

```
uses
  Windows, TlHelp32, ...

function WindowHandleToEXEName(handle : THandle) : string;
var
  snap : THandle;
  pe : tagPROCESSENTRY32;
  pid : THandle;
  found : boolean;
begin
  Windows.SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS);

  result := '';
  if (handle = 0) then exit;

  snap := TLHelp32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
  if (snap = Cardinal(-1)) then exit;

  Windows.GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, @pid);
  pe.dwSize := Sizeof(pe);
  found := TLHelp32.Process32First(snap, pe);

  while found do
  begin
    if (pe.th32ProcessID = pid) then
    begin
      result := String(pe.szExeFile);
      break;
    end;
    found := TLHelp32.Process32Next(snap, pe);
  end;
  CloseHandle(snap);
end;
```

Comment: Why take a snapshot of all processes when you can directly get the information you want?

Comment: Why is your function always claiming to be successful? Why using a variable like `found` and a `while` loop at all when a `repeat` loop would make more sense?

Answer (score 3):

Given any valid `HWND`, you can do the following:

- use [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) to get the process ID that created it.
- then use  [`OpenProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess) to open a `HANDLE` to that process.
- then use either [`GetModuleFileNameEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexw), [`GetProcessImageFileName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getprocessimagefilenamew), or [`QueryFullProcessImageName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamew) (depending on OS version) to get the file path of the EXE that created that process.